# What is the best way to make swirl hair with modeling?

Tags: modeling, mesh, hair

I want to make the perfect swirl of hair. I don't want any hair particles or something just models only. See the tiny swirl hairs in front? that I want to make. this picture is from "Spiraling Witch Encyclopedia Marie".
[image]

Make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it myself.

Comment: Have you tried extruded curves aka hair tubes? Just beware the result can get fairly high-poly with these curves and there can be a lot of intersections. Videos: [Hair with Curves](https://youtu.be/t2XjdzzWCqI) and [The Many Ways to Poly-Model Hair](https://youtu.be/xyUXfjBtanA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base mesh for the swirls by using Skin modifier along with Subdivision Surface modifier:

1. Starting with a vertex, extrude it several times to make the swirl shape:

[image]

2. Then add both modifiers and adjust every vertex size with CTRL+A or by setting Radius X/Y values as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I hope this helps.